# Cochrane Gambit book recommendations?

Tags: gambits

Are there any good books that explain how the Cochrane Gambit works from white's perspective?

Comment: I was wondering if there is enough material to write a book about Cochrane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on youtube there are an number of videos by strong players
e.g. Miodrag Perunovic is 50 mins long.
It is probably worth a try in quick games if you are frustrated at the normal symmetrical Petrovs

Comment: To clarify - the original question seems to have been changed - my response was specifically about the Cochrane gambit.

Answer (score 1):

[This page from Michael Goeller at The Kenilworthian](http://kenilworthian.blogspot.com/2011/03/cochrane-gambit.html) seems to offer a definitive guide. The printed books listed there which discuss the gambit from the white perspective are:

- *The Alterman Gambit Guide: White Gambits*, B. Alterman (contains 40 pages on the gambit)
- *A Startling Chess Opening Repetoire*, C. Baker (contains 16 pages on the gambit)

The Kenilworthian lists a few other books, most of which are either from non-GM authors or not from the white perspective. It also has a collection of web resources (some of which are no longer available, but you can [use the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190116012625/www.schach.gmxhome.de/boofreng.htm)) and videos.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Amazon books, you will find several titles listed, but nothing by a recognised author, so buyer beware. The response from deva does look horribly Chat_GPTish but it is uncanny that if any GM had written about the Cochrane it probably would be Gary Lane. However, his web site does not mention one.